# g++ server.cpp -Wall

Tags: g++, runit

I have a program written in C++ in Linux I just download Vim editor I gave this command to compile:

```
g++ server.cpp -Wall
```

when I come to run it I use `./a` but

it does not work can give me the correct command to run the file.

Thanks.

Comment: The default binary name `a.out` isn't it?

Comment: yep `./a.out` is the default.  Or the OP could just run `make server` and get a binary called `./server`, relying on `make`'s default rules, even without a `Makefile`.

Answer (score 1):

The default executable name is `a.out`, according to the `g++` manpage:

```
-o file

    Place output in file file.  This applies to whatever sort
    of output is being produced, whether it be an executable file,
    an object file, an assembler file or preprocessed C code.

    If -o is not specified, the default is to put an executable file
    in a.out, the object file for source.suffix in source.o, its
    assembler file in source.s, a precompiled header file in
    source.suffix.gch, and all preprocessed C source on standard output.
```

So, you can use `./a.out` to run the compiled executable or add the `-o` argument to the `g++` command line:

```
$ g++ -o server server.cpp -Wall
$ ./server
```